Invalid arara error when running YAML directive from TeXShop
I'm using arara to play a Waves.mp3 sound file when TeXShop starts, and completes, typesetting my LuaLaTeX project file (~20 minutes), mainly as a gentle alert that the typesetting is complete.
The first two lines of my .tex project file are:
% !TEX TS-program = arara
% arara: play-sound

where the play-sound.yaml file (located in my /users/<username> folder) contains the following:
!config
# Arara custom rule to play a sound after compilation
#
# author: Your Name
# date: 2024-06-30
# version: 1.0

identifier: play-sound
name: Play Sound Rule
commands:
   -  name: Play Sound
      command: 'afplay "/Users/<username>/Music/Special_Sounds/Waves.mp3"'

As a check that the Waves.mp3 file is available, I'm able to play the Waves.mp3 file from within Terminal using the command:
> afplay "/Users/<username>/Music/Special_Sounds/Waves.mp3"

My .araraconfig.yaml arara configuration file, located in my /users/<username> directory is as follows:
!config
paths:
   -  /home/@{user.name}/rules
loops: 30
verbose: true
logging: true
header: true
logname: mytexlog.txt

The java version is:
java -version
openjdk version "22.0.1" 2024-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 22.0.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 22.0.1, mixed mode, sharing)

The TeXShop version is: Version 5.36 (5.36)
When I typeset my LuaLaTeX project using TeXShop, I see the error:
I spotted an invalid directive (2) in the provided file. Make sure to fix the directive and try again.

The contents of my mytexlog.txt log file from the recent TeXShop typesetting run are:
01 Jul 2024 18:51:03.724 INFO  - 
Welcome to arara 7.1.5!
-----------------------------------------------------------------
01 Jul 2024 18:51:03.726 DEBUG - 
::: arara @ /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/scripts/arara
::: Java 22.0.1, Homebrew
::: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/22.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
::: Mac OS X, aarch64, 14.5
::: user.home @ /Users/<username>
::: CF @ /Users/<username>/.araraconfig.yaml
-----------------------------------------------------------------
01 Jul 2024 18:51:03.730 INFO  - Processing "Differ2Latex-v32i9.tex" (size: 3.2 MB, last modified: 2024-07-02 01:50:54), please wait.
01 Jul 2024 18:51:03.807 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 2: play-sound
01 Jul 2024 18:51:03.807 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 5: clean: { extensions: [aux, bbl, bcf, blg, glg, glo, gls, alg, acr, acn, ayg, ayh, ayi, byg, byh, byi, cyg, cyh, cyi, dyg, dyh, dyi, eyg, eyh, eyi, fyg, fyh, fyi, gyg, gyh, gyi, hyg, hyh, hyi, iyg, iyh, iyi, jyg, jyh, jyi, idx, ind, log, out, run.xml, slnc, tex~, toc] }
01 Jul 2024 18:51:03.807 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 10: lualatex: { synctex: on, shell: on, options: "--stack-size=70000" }
01 Jul 2024 18:51:03.807 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 11: lualatex: { synctex: on, shell: yes, options: "--stack-size=70000" }
01 Jul 2024 18:51:03.807 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 15: biber
01 Jul 2024 18:51:03.807 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 16: makeglossaries if missing('gls') || changed('glo')
01 Jul 2024 18:51:03.807 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 18: makeindex: { style: Differ2Latex-v32i9.ist }
01 Jul 2024 18:51:03.807 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 19: makeindex: { style: Differ2Latex-v32i9.ist } if changed ('idx') || missing ('ind')
01 Jul 2024 18:51:03.807 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 20: nomencl
01 Jul 2024 18:51:03.807 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 21: makeglossaries if found('aux', '@istfilename')
01 Jul 2024 18:51:03.807 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 22: lualatex: { synctex: on, shell: yes, options: "--stack-size=70000" }
01 Jul 2024 18:51:03.807 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 23: biber
01 Jul 2024 18:51:03.807 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 24: makeindex: { style: Differ2Latex-v32i9.ist } if changed ('idx') || missing ('ind')
01 Jul 2024 18:51:03.807 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 25: makeglossaries if missing('gls') || changed('glo')
01 Jul 2024 18:51:03.807 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 26: lualatex: { synctex: on, shell: yes, options: "--stack-size=70000" }
01 Jul 2024 18:51:03.807 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 27: authorindex
01 Jul 2024 18:51:03.808 ERROR - I spotted an invalid directive (2) in the provided file. Make sure to fix the directive and try again.
01 Jul 2024 18:51:03.809 INFO  - Total: 0.188 seconds

What am I missing?
Any thoughts or ideas to look for would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks for reading.
P.S. Regarding the reference on the SE site at How to use arara with TeXShop, I've already moved the arara.engine file from the ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/Inactive/Arara folder to the ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines folder.

UPDATE 5 July 2024:
Following along with the recommendations from
cfr, Alan Munn and Paulo Cereda, I successfully adjusted the YAML configuration and code to have my /Users/<username>/arara/rules/playsound.yaml file execute from within my arara code while typesetting my LuaLaTeX project using TeXShop. (What a mouthful!)
To start, my araraconfig.yaml is hidden within my <username> folder as /Users/<username>/.araraconfig.yaml (Notice the period (.) b4 the araraconfig.yaml file.)
(For those neophytes like me, access for the hidden files and folders is available on MacOS via the shift-command-period(.) keystroke combination.)
Next, the contents of my /Users/<username>/.araraconfig.yaml file sets up my arara log file mytexlog.txt to follow along when arara executes:
!config
paths:
- /Users/<username>/arara/rules

loops: 30
verbose: true
logging: true
header: true
logname: mytexlog.txt

Then, I needed to add the rules folder within the /Users/<username>/arara folder to create the /Users/<username>/arara/rules folder.
Lastly, I created/modified my /Users/<username>/arara/rules/playsound.yaml file as follows:
!config
#
identifier: playsound
name: Play Sound Rule
commands:
- name: Play Sound
  command: >
    @{[
       getCommand('afplay', '/Users/<username>/Music/Special_Sounds/Waves.mp3');
    ]}
arguments: []

Thanks to both Alan Munn and Paulo Cereda, as well as cfr for their patience and effort to make this happen.
My only hope is others may benefit from now having a way to create an alert when their LaTeX/arara package is done typesetting.
I now have a new tool to arrange my workflow around my day.

Not sure where the configuration directory is on Macs these days, but are you sure it should be in the top-level of your home? It's a long time since I did this, so perhaps arara is more flexible now, but I have a config file, for example, araraconfig.yaml in ~/.arara/ and then files defining directives in ~/.arara/rules and ~/.arara/rules.extra, though I'm not sure they shouldn't be in ~/.config/arara by now.  But I wouldn't expect arara to pick up random .yaml files from my home directory and would be rather alarmed if it did.

@cfr Thanks for the comment. In the mytexlog.txt file (see above), it confirms that arara is reading the configuration file when it says: CF @ /Users/<username>/.araraconfig.yaml. I presume the CF means Configuration File. Also, the fact that the mytexlog.txt log file exists indicates that arara IS reading the configuration file.

@cfr Re your suggestion regarding placing my YAML play-sound.yaml file into the ~/.arara and ~/.arara/rules folders. I tried placing the YAML file in both the ~/.arara and ~/.arara/rules folders. I then restarted TeXShop, and re-typeset the project file, but the same arara error appeared. Not sure what you mean by I'm not sure they shouldn't be in ~/.config/arara by now.

@cfr Re your suggestion I'm not sure they shouldn't be in ~/.config/arara by now. I created the ~/.config/arara folder and placed a copy of my play-sound.yaml file in the folder. I then restarted TeXShop, and re-typeset the LaTeX project file, but the same arara error appeared.

I didn't necessarily mean that was the correct place on your system. Macs probably want the files somewhere else. And you're right about the config file. Sorry for missing that. Do you list the custom file in your config? You can always pass --verbose to get more information. There is also texdoc arara.

@cfr Thank you for your comment. I looked through the arara Ref. manual, but I did not see where/how to list the custom file in your config. Could you be more specific? (I'm an arara neophyte.) What am I missing? Any thoughts as to what may be blocking arara from running w my setup? I expect this will likely be a long haul issue to remedy the blockage. I've been working on this for several months now.

So you need to remove the hyphen, tell arara where to find custom rules and update the syntax.
Thanks to Alan Munn and Paulo Cereda for solving this.
Note that I cannot test this exact setup as I'm not on a Mac, but an analogous case which prints 'Hylo Byd!' works on Linux. I'm including the 'Hylo Byd!' rule partly because Paulo wants me to include Welsh in this answer and partly so you can test that one as a sanity check if necessary.
But first you probably want something like this in your configuration file. You can put your rules where you prefer provided you point arara to them properly.
So in /Users/<username>/araraconfig.yaml you want something similar to
!config
paths:
- /Users/<username>/arara/rules

Then you need a file such as /Users/<username>/arara/rules/hylobyd.yaml. Testing by three of us in chat has established that omitting the hyphen from the name is crucial.
!config
#
identifier: hylobyd
name: Hylo Byd Rule
commands:
- name: Hylo Byd
  command: >
    @{[
       getCommand('printf', '%b', 'Hylo Byd!');
    ]}
arguments: []

So you will need a file such as /Users/<username>/arara/rules/playsound.yaml.
!config
#
identifier: playsound
name: Play Sound Rule
commands:
- name: Play Sound
  command: >
    @{[
       getCommand('afplay', '/Users/<username>/Music/Special_Sounds/Waves.mp3');
    ]}
arguments: []


@Alan Munn and @cfr - Thank you both for your marvellous effort. I am making progress, but I need more time to work this through. It is a bit late here, so if you will allow me, I will pick this up tomorrow with (hopefully) good news. This is looking very helpful as it appears the invalid directive is no longer happening, but I did not hear the sound of the Waves.mp3 file playing. Must be something I'm still doing wrong. Thank you both again!

@Alan Munn and @cfr - OK ... It WORKED!! My error was placing the rules folder inside the hidden .arara folder, instead of just the plain /Users/<username>/arara/rules folder. When I've had some sleep, I'd like to document what I did to get this to work, after applying the changes you recommended. Thank you both. There is NO way I would have had any chance to get this to work w/o your assistance. I cannot thank you both enough.

@RosesBouquet You can only ping one person in a comment. However, as this is my answer, I'm pinged automatically so just ping Alan Munn.
